# Console log statements on React event handler causes synthetic event warnings

Tags: reactjs

Code Sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/0olpzq7n3n

It's some pretty straight forward code:

```
const Form = ({ form, updateForm }) => {
  const handleChange = (event, value) => {
    console.log(event, value);
    console.log(event.target.name, event.target.value);

    const newForm = { ...form, ...{ [event.target.name]: event.target.value } };
    updateForm(newForm);
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <input
        name="value1"
        value={form.value1}
        onChange={event => handleChange(event)}
      />
    </form>
  );
};

const Form1 = connect(
  state => ({ form: state.form1 }),
  dispatch => ({ updateForm: newForm => dispatch(updateFormOne(newForm)) })
)(Form);

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2> Welcome to the Home route</h2>
      <Form1 />
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you edit the form input in this scenario it gives these warnings:

```
Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `nativeEvent` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist(). See (shortend URL that StackOverflow doesn't like).
```

If I remove those console log statements, the warning disappears.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to `console.log()` an asynchronous synthetic event that is removed by the time the `callback` is executed. If you wish to to persist the event, then use `event.persist()`.

Using `event.persist()`, you can see all of the `event` properties:

```
ispatchConfig: Object
_targetInst: FiberNode
nativeEvent: InputEvent
type: "change"
target: <input name="value1" value="this is form a1"></input>
currentTarget: null
eventPhase: 3
bubbles: true
cancelable: false
timeStamp: 2926.915000000008
defaultPrevented: false
isTrusted: true
isDefaultPrevented: function () {}
isPropagationStopped: function () {}
_dispatchListeners: null
_dispatchInstances: null
isPersistent: function () {}
<constructor>: "SyntheticEvent"
```

More information about synthetic events can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling%20and) and [here](https://medium.com/trabe/react-syntheticevent-reuse-889cd52981b6).

However, if you already know what you want from the `event`, then you can [destructure](https://codeburst.io/es6-destructuring-the-complete-guide-7f842d08b98f) its properties like so:

```
const handleChange = ({ target: { value, name } }) => {
    console.log(name, value);

    const newForm = { ...form, [name]: value };
    updateForm(newForm);
  };
```