# What is meaning of "nullified object" in SyntheticEvent of React?

Tags: reactjs, dom-events

I learned that React manages DOM event handlers as SyntheticEvent object. Also, I know this object is pooled for performance reason. It means that it is cannot used in asynchronous context like `setTimeout()` or `setState()`. However, why the warning is appeared when I `console.log(e)` in event handler function? Docs says it is "nullified object", but I cannot understand exact meaning of this. I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54565733/11789111) and it says that object is removed when handler is invoked. Then, I'm curious that why property of event object is accessible even if that object is removed? Is there anyone who can explain the meaning of "nullfied object" in SyntheticEvent clearly? Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: this synthetic event object will be available in the main event handler. Any async calls that could be triggered in this handler and if those invoked functions tries to access the event object then you would get this error. Bcoz, the main event handler has been completed and the event object is returned to the pool and the reference is nullified. So the async calls that are still executing after the main handler has completed may not access this. If you need so you might need to call `event.presist()`

Comment: Console.log isn't nearly as synchronous as people expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Nullifying an object means setting the values of its properties to **null**.
Consider an example:

```
const event = { type: 'click' }

// after nullification 
event = { type: null }
```

So, as you can see, the reference to the same object (event) has been maintained for performance reasons, but the value for `type` has been set to **null**.

Just a side note that React v17.0 removes the "event pooling" optimization.